# Fetch xlsx file from email and copy file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I saw this script from one of the questions here, but can't make it work. It is meant to fetch an Excel file from my Gmail and copy it to a Google Sheet. Google Sheet file is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rED5zphZKp7JIK9qaTpHLKBSMsSiLAvhBAXc6Tn0zqI/edit#gid=301517543

Script:

```
function getRawData() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:myRentokil Report Delivery: Canpac | Pest Activity');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  var xlsxBlob = attachment[0]; // Is supposes that attachment[0] is the blob of xlsx file.
  var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0]; // There is the data in 1st tab.
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Drive.Files.remove(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rED5zphZKp7JIK9qaTpHLKBSMsSiLAvhBAXc6Tn0zqI").getSheetByName("RawData");
  sheet.clearContents();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);range.setValues(data);

 }
```

Comment: Try turning on DriveAPI in the service section of the script editor.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Hi it's working now, but, I had to remove the line "Drive.Files.remove(convertedSpreadsheetId);" this means that converted sheets will pile up on my drive. How can I automatically delete the temporary sheet. 
Error message shows:
Error 
Document 15ntCXkDasViXnrqlTfI6hjWvAch_hXqS8a2r9ybmXRU is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modified Script

```
function getRawData() {
    // This gets the threads
    var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:excel attachment');
    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0]; // returns the first message from the first thread
    var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0]; // returns the first attachment
    var xlsxBlob = attachment; // This is a blob, yes.
    
    var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // gets values from first tab
    
    // You were overwriting some variables here, so changed to dataSheet and dataRange
    var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rED5zphZKp7JIK9qaTpHLKBSMsSiLAvhBAXc6Tn0zqI").getSheetByName("RawData");
    var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
    dataRange.setValues(data);
    
    // Moved this line to the end because you were deleting it before using the data inside it.
    // Changed to trash instead of remove.
    Drive.Files.trash(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.
 }
```

- I commented your script to make the steps clearer.
- There were some variables that were initialized twice so just changed those names.
- The reason for the error is that `remove` does not exist as a method in the Drive API v2.

  [image]

  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/trash

  `remove` actually does seem to work and deletes the file, but it always returns the error. `trash` works as expected. If you want to skip the trash you can `delete` instead.